# Json True/False in PHP

Tags: php, json, boolean, redirect

I need a little help on Json Boolean in PHP as I'm kinda new in programming, had been trying to figure out how to get this to work.

So basically what the Json will return is if I'm online, it will show `{"isonline":true}` and if I'm offline it shows `{"isonline":false}`.

What I want to make is that whenever a visitor come to my site, in `index.php` will check whether if I'm online or not. If I'm online, redirect the user to `http://www.example.com/online.php` and if I'm offline, redirect user to `http://www.example.com/leave-message.php`.

Appreciate any help! Thanks.

Comment: You `json_decode()` the JSON into an array or object, then you check the `isonline` key of that array or object, then you redirect with `header()` to one or the other with an `if..else` statement. Try something.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I'm still kinda new to this. How can I check or create a check for `isonline` if it's true or false?

Comment: As simple as `if ($somevar) ..`. Just replace `$somevar` with your decoded JSON variable. This really is all extremely basic; please try to figure it out yourself, Stackoverflow is hardly the place to get taught the basics of programming. I suggest you look up the specifics of the functions I mentioned above in the manual and have a look at the examples: http://php.net